# Laravel: Call function on sync or attach

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Whenever I modify a relationship (many to many) I want to do another action. As far as I know this can't be done using event listeners (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2303). This works,

```
function setUserGroups($ids){
   $this->groups->sync($ids);
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

The downside is that it's not intuitive for other developers to remember to use this function. Generally I'm able to attach behavior to change in other attributes using mutators, defining them as guarded or adding events, and I just want to be able to do something similar with syncing/attaching.

I don't see creating a repository as a solution for this. We're not using the repository pattern in our application and honestly I see this issue coming up there as well.

Comment: 3 1/2 years and no solutions. The best I've found so far is to use "updating" eloquent method, but it's callred right before updating on the DB, useful to calculate fields, but maybe not the solution for everyone.

Comment: I ended up converting my pivots into their own models in the end

Answer (score 0):

You may register your custom event handlers and listeners:

```
// register listener
Event::listen('user.groupsModified', 'User@onGroupsModified');
```

Event Handler:

```
// Handle event in User class
function onGroupsModified($event)
{

}
```

Then fire the event in `setUserGroups` function:

```
function setUserGroups($ids){

    $this->groups->sync($ids);

    // Fire the event
    Event->fire('user.groupsModified');
}
```

This way, you can abstract the dependency from the `setUserGroups` method, now you only need to fire the event and no need to know the handler's name.

Comment: the issue is that devs still need to remember to call setUserGroups, whereas normally when modifying a relationship they can just call sync directly without any problems. I've found that in general laravel is great for attaching behaviors to eloquent methods/modifying attributes (so you don't need to remember to call wrapper functions), this is the only example I've found that I can't get around.

Comment: Developers only need to remember to fire `Event->fire('user.groupsModified')`.

Comment: It's true that it's better than calling a custom method but I still feel like there should be way to hook that in somehow...